# a pure kotlin way of implementing publish-subscribe pattern which is type aware

Tags: kotlin, publish-subscribe

I'm wondering how can I implement a simple publish-subscribe pattern in kotlin with such APIs:

```
Channel.publish(event: T)
Channel.subscribe{ event: T -> Unit)
```

Type awareness is important to me, So that the `Channel` will only deliver events of type `T` to a subscriber of type `(T)->Unit` (and not to another one of type `(S)->Unit` which `S is T` equals to `false`)

Here is my implementation. 
But two things bothers me. Look:

```
import kotlin.reflect.KClass

object Channel {

    private val subscribers: MutableMap<KClass<*>, (Any) -> Unit> = mutableMapOf()

    inline fun <reified T> publish(event: T) {
        subscribers[T::class]?.invoke(event as Any)
    }

    inline fun <reified T> subscribe(noinline subscriber: (T) -> Unit) {
        subscribers[T::class] = subscriber as (Any) -> Unit
    }

}

data class Person(val name: String)

fun main() {
    Channel.subscribe { person: Person -> println("Hello ${person.name}") }
    Channel.publish(Person("John"))
}
```

The casts `event as Any` and `subscriber as (Any) -> Unit` looks dummy to me. How can I get rid of this? Is it possible in this problem?

**UPDATE #1:**
I found a solution to get rid of `event as Any`

```
    inline fun <reified T : Any> publish(event: T) {
        subscribers[T::class]?.invoke(event)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation will work for a very naive case. But for example, multiple subscribers for a single same event type isn't supported in the code above.
Same goes for the case of subscribing to a supertype of an event. (i.e. event hierarchies)

Unless you're building this as an exercise I suggest you use an existing implementation like [Guava's event bus](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/EventBusExplained). It's not written in Kotlin but in Java but it works smoothly with Kotlin.